# How do we project a coordinate in 4-dimensions to that of a 3-dimensional coordinate?

Tags: projective-geometry, projection

So essentially what I'm asking is this: so let's say that I have a set of points that I arrange into a sphere. Now, with those same points I arrange them into that of a hypersphere. How do I convert the coordinates of a point in that hypersphere into coordinates of where the point would be if the points were assembled into a 3d sphere instead of its 4d hypersphere form.

Essentially project a 4-d coordinate to a 3-d one assuming that a 3-d shape retains the amount of points it has when it is shaped into its 4-d version. Essentially a sphere is rearranged into a hypersphere with the same amount of points. How do I convert a 4-d coordinate on the hypersphere into a 3-d coordinate on the sphere.

I have no formal understanding of projective geometry and I'm a bit iffy with vectors. I hope this question is understandable enough. Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! <> To complement the existing answer, we can put a "point light source" at $(0, 0, 0, h)$ for some $h \neq 0$. A point $(x, y, z, w)$ with $w \neq h$ casts a shadow at $\frac{h}{h-w}(x, y, z)$. This projection gives a sense of "four-dimensional depth" so long as $h$ is larger than the fourth coordinate of each point being projected.

Answer (score 1):

Represent a point in spherical coordinates:

$$\begin{pmatrix} x\\y\\z\\w \end{pmatrix}
= r \begin{pmatrix}
\sin\phi \sin\psi \sin\theta \\
\sin\phi \sin\psi \cos\theta \\
\sin\phi \cos\psi \\
\cos\phi\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
then you can project on the equator by letting $\phi=\pi/2$.  This gives you spherical coordinates in $(x,y,z)$:

$$\begin{pmatrix} x\\y\\z \end{pmatrix}
= r \begin{pmatrix}
\sin\psi \sin\theta \\
\sin\psi \cos\theta \\
\cos\psi \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Notice however than when you are on a 3-sphere, i.e. $r=1$, then this will project to a 2-dimensional space, namely the 2-sphere.

If you want to retain more information and just project into a 3-dimensional space, you may want to use other projections like [parallel projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_projection).  The easiest such projection is to just "forget" one coordinate:

$$\begin{align}
\Bbb R^4 &\to \Bbb R^3 \\
(x,y,z,w) &\mapsto (x,y,z)
\end{align}$$

For more flexibility, take a basis of $\Bbb R^4$ that's ortho-normal, say $e_1, \dots, e_4$ and write the points $P$ uniquely as:

$$P=\sum_{i=1}^4 p_i e_i$$
where the $p_i$ are the coordinates with respect to the $e_i$.  Then do a parallel projection by taking $p_1, p_2, p_3$ as coordinates in $\Bbb R^3$, i.e. you just forget the 4th coordinate.  This is then a parallel projection to the 3d-space spanned by $e_1, e_2, e_3$.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. Just to clarify, is psi any arbitrary angle?

Comment: @Cease Desist: In the 3d-case and with the notation above, $\psi$ is sometimes called [colatitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colatitude) and $\theta$ is [azimuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azimuth).  If you prefer $\sin\psi\leftrightarrow\cos\psi$ then $\psi$ would be [latitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latitude).